# Where does a file have to be for terminal to find it?

Tags: linux, terminal, vnc

I'm trying to use rpm to install a file through the linux terminal. The file I'm currently trying to install is in my downloads folder and is named: `vnc-server.rpm`

But when I type `rpm -Uvh linux-server.rpm` into the terminal, I get: `error: open of vnc-server.rpm failed: No such directory or file.`

But that file clearly does exist because it's right here. Does it need to be in a specific place for terminal to find it?

**Update:** I tried using the 'ls' command so find the file directory using it both regularly and with sudo and it could not find the file. But somehow, moving it out of my downloads folder immediately fixed the issue.

Now I was able to try to install the file, but it still failed because I'm missing a bunch of dependencies.

Comment: Write a small part of the file name and press <Tab>, and the terminal will auto-complete the file name for you. This takes care of spelling errors and such. In this case you say the file is named `linux-server` but the error message clearly indicates that you ran the command with the argument `vnc-server` (it is probable that your problem description of `linux-server` is a typo, though).

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo, on my computer both the file and my attempts used the name vnc-server.rpm

Comment: Also, pressing <Tab> doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: The file has to be in the current directory of your terminal session. Do you know about this and `cd`? Are you sure that you give the correct path to the file? Try the command `ls` with your file name as argument. Can `ls` find it? If not, the problem is not related to `rpm` in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unless for some reason the permissions on your download folder have changed, which would require you to preface your command with *sudo*.

See if this fixes your problem:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rpm-command-no-such-file-directory-error.html

Comment: I was not able to find it using the `ls` command. So I moved it out of the downloads folder to see if that would make a difference and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible that you are not currently in the Downloads folder (or wherever the desired file is located)? Try typing `pwd` command in the terminal and see which path it returns. If it is not the same path as the file then it's not that weird.

Alternatively you can check the files that are in the working directory with `ls -l` command, and try to see if the file is listed there.

If the auto-complete doesnt work then it's most likely that you are not in the right working directory, try to use the  `cd` command to change the working directory to where the file is located.